# Remove partial duplicates from text file

Tags: bash, awk

My bash-foo is a little rusty right now so I wanted to see if there's a clever way to remove partial duplicates from a file. I have a bunch of files containing thousands of lines with the following format:

```
String1|String2|String3|String4|String5|String6|...|String22|09-Apr-2016 05:28:03|x
```

Essentially it's a bunch of pipe delimited strings, with the final two columns being a timestamp and x. What I'd like to do is concatenate all of my files and then remove all partial duplicates. I'm defining partial duplicate as a line in the file that matches from String1 up to String22, but the timestamp can be different.

For example, a file containing:

```
String1|String2|String3|String4|String5|String6|...|String22|09-Apr-2016 05:28:03|x
String1|String2|String3|String4|String5|String6|...|String22|09-Apr-2016 12:12:12|x
String124|String2|String3|String4|String5|String6|...|String22|09-Apr-2016 05:28:03|x
```

would become:

```
String1|String2|String3|String4|String5|String6|...|String22|09-Apr-2016 05:28:03|x
String124|String2|String3|String4|String5|String6|...|String22|09-Apr-2016 05:28:03|x
```

(It doesn't matter which timestamp is chosen).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `awk` you can do this:

```
awk '{k=$0; gsub(/(\|[^|]*){2}$/, "", k)} !seen[k]++' file

String1|String2|String3|String4|String5|String6|String7|09-Apr-2016 05:28:03|x
String124|String2|String3|String4|String5|String6|String7|09-Apr-2016 05:28:03|x
```

`awk` command first makes a variable `k` by removing last 2 fields from each line. Then it uses an associative array `seen` with key as `k` where it prints only first instance of key by storing each processes key in the array.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Bash version 4, which supports associative arrays, it can be done fairly efficiently in pure Bash:

```
declare -A found
while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n $line ]] ; do
    strings=${line%|*|*}
    if (( ! ${found[$strings]-0} )) ; then
        printf '%s\n' "$line"
        found[$strings]=1
    fi
done < "$file"
```

Comment: Replace `fairly efficiently` with `very inefficiently` - this would run an order of magnitude slower than an equivalent awk script for a reasonably large file. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Answer (score 0):

same idea with @anubhava, but I think more idiomatic

```
$ awk -F'|' '{line=$0;$NF=$(NF-1)=""} !a[$0]++{print line}' file

String1|String2|String3|String4|String5|String6|...|String22|09-Apr-2016 05:28:03|x
String124|String2|String3|String4|String5|String6|...|String22|09-Apr-2016 05:28:03|x
```

Comment: That's less idiomatic (the idiomatic array name is `seen[]` and you would not want to hard-code a list of fields to be set to null) and it's fragile because it will replace all `|`s in `$0` with blank chars so you could no longer tell `a|b c` from `a b|c` - they'd both become `a b c` when used in `a[$0]++`.